# Computing open circuit voltage (Thévenin equivalent)

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I want to know how I can solve this problem and hope you can explain this in detail.

[image]

Then I made a parallel connection and got this:

[image]

After this I also simplified my circuit and got stuck here:

[image]

Comment: 1) Step looks good. The numbers in 2) step figure, but check again what Thévenin's theorem postulates as the replacement. Where's the voltage the question asked about?

Comment: I found formula, V(0) =  E * R2/R1+R2 but I cannot understand what value I should use for R1 and R2 for example in this case using formula I got two possible solutions in which only 1 is correct, **if I take R2 as 2/3 my answer is 1/4 but if take R2 as 2 my answer is 3/4**

Comment: What is `E` (`R1, R2`) in `E * R2/R1+R2`? The schematic shows a current source.

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt show what is R1 value and R2  value, so I confuse here, which value should I take to use formula.

Comment: Meanwhile, replace the subcircuit of current source and parallel resistor *from 1) step* with the Thévenin equivalent of voltage source and series resistor. Do you still find an application for your formula? Mind that just the A-B voltage is required - computing a resulting resistance looks optional.

Comment: @Mirmir your 2) step is wrong. In fact, you can be done simplifying your schematic after your 1st step if you know how to apply current division such that you find the current through the 1Ohm resistor across the B & A terminals. Check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are FAR easier ways to solve this problem without resorting to brute-force KCL/KVL equations.**

I'll refer to the following circuit when solving your problem, it's basically your circuit with an extra label C at the top of the current source so that it'll help me explain better what I'm doing.

There are many ways, but I can see 2 ways in which you can get results with just 2 equations.

I have taken the liberty to simplify the 2 parallel \$2\Omega\$
resistors to \$1\Omega\$, as you have correctly recognized in your 1st step.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBlaSE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**1) Current division approach:**

I1 current source will feed currents through the R1-R2 branch and the R3 branch. The current will *divided* between these 2 branches. Therefore, we can apply the current division formula to obtain the current through the R1-R2 branch:
$$
I_{R1,R2} = I1 \frac{R3}{R3+R2+R1} = 1A\frac{2\Omega}{2\Omega + 1\Omega +1\Omega} = 0.5A
$$
Now that we have the current through the R1-R2 branch, all we need to do is multiply by R1 in order to obtain the voltage drop across terminals B and A (i.e. the open-circuit thevenin voltage).
$$
V_{th}=I_{R1,R2}\times R1 = I1 \frac{R3}{R3+R2+R1}\times R1 = 1A\frac{2\Omega}{2\Omega + 1\Omega +1\Omega} (1\Omega) = 0.5V
$$

**2) Voltage division approach:**

A resistor in parallel with a current source can be transformed into a voltage in series with the same resistor. It's, basically, taking the thévenin equivalent of this "Norton" type of input source.

Therefore, these 2 networks are equivalent:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTrjLT.png)</sup>

How do we justify this?
Find the open voltage across R1_nrt. this equals 2V.
Find its equivalent impedance: to this end, we shut down any source. A shut-down current source is an open. Therefore, we are left with the \$2 \Omega\$ resistor. We, then, arrive the voltage source + resistor equivalent network.

Therefore, we have transformed the original schematic to the following equivalent schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyPUmK.png)</sup>

Once we have this schematic, it's trivial (I hope) to see that the voltage across B-A (or across R1) is just plain voltage division:
$$
V_{B,A} = V_{th} = V1\frac{R1}{R1+R2+R3} = 2V\frac{1}{1+1+2} = 0.5V
$$

Now, if you want to find the equivalent impedance, you can either zero the voltage source (short it) or the current source (open it) in either schematic and solving for the equivalent resistance should be trivial.

Comment: Thank you! I have 2 questions only for step1 (Current division approach)

1) Why you want to find especially " I r1 and r2 " I just confuse, because there are also r3.

2) Question about this  "all we need to do is multiply by R1 in order to obtain the voltage drop across terminals B and A (i.e. the open-circuit thevenin voltage)."  We multiply by R1 just because R1 is located/connects between A and B terminals? Am I get it correctly?

Comment: @Mirmir we're interested only in the voltage across R1 as it's exactly Vba. However, to do so, we need to find the current across that resistor. If you find that, you know that, by Ohm's law, that the voltage across the resistor will just be Ir1*R1. So yes to your question 2.

Comment: The other way is to use voltage division, then you can skip all this current calculation and just find the voltage drop across R1.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faDSy5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_\text{s}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{s}&=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_5
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_5}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
0&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_\text{s}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{s}&=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_5}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{0 == I1 + I2 + I3 + I5, I0 == Is + I2, I4 == I0 + I3, 
   Is == I4 + I6, I6 == I1 + I5, I1 == V1/R1, I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, 
   I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, I4 == V2/R4, I5 == V1/R5}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4,
    I5, I6, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> (Is (R1 R3 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)))/(
   R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
    R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I1 -> (Is (R2 + R3) R4 R5)/(
   R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
    R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I2 -> -((Is R3 R4 (R1 + R5))/(
    R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
     R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5))), 
  I3 -> -((Is R2 R4 (R1 + R5))/(
    R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
     R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5))), 
  I4 -> (Is (R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R5))/(
   R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
    R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I5 -> (Is R1 (R2 + R3) R4)/(
   R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
    R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  I6 -> (Is (R2 + R3) R4 (R1 + R5))/(
   R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
    R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V1 -> (Is R1 (R2 + R3) R4 R5)/(
   R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
    R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), 
  V2 -> (Is R4 (R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R5))/(
   R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
    R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5))}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_1\$ and letting \$\text{R}_5\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{I}_\text{s}\text{R}_1\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag4$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_5\$ and letting \$\text{R}_5\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{I}_\text{s}\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag5$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_3\text{R}_4}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(Is R1 (R2 + R3) R4 R5)/(
  R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
   R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), R5 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=(Is R1 (R2 + R3) R4)/(R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(Is R1 (R2 + R3) R4)/(
  R3 R4 R5 + R2 (R3 + R4) R5 + R1 R3 (R4 + R5) + 
   R1 R2 (R3 + R4 + R5)), R5 -> 0]]

Out[3]=(Is (R2 + R3) R4)/(R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=(R1 (R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)))/(R1 (R2 + R3) + R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4))
```

So, using your values we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{1}{2}=0.5\space\text{V}\tag7$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{2}{3}\approx0.666667\space\text{A}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{3}{4}=0.75\space\Omega\tag9$$

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote on my answer?

Comment: Wasn't me. +1 from me "jut because". I don't know why the downvote BUT it may be kickback from someone due to "other recent issues" which I have recently commenmted on and which some are quite sensitive about. (See recent meta discussion. ) If so it is probably a short term thing.

Comment: @JanEerland I am sorry, but you used other schema?